# Scrapy doesn't call callback function even with no filter

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have this code to crawl the details page

```
yield Request(flexibleItem[self.linkAttributeName],callback=self.parseDetails,dont_filter=True  )
```

there is no error in the subURL because I tested it with the same method "GET"

I didn't get any error but simply python ignoring the callback function

It is a very huge project working on a server so I can't share the code .
But here is the main architecture for what I am doing .
Output is :
**in start request
TRUE
oooo**

```
def start_requests(self):
    print "in start request"
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request (url, method='GET',dont_filter=True)

def parse(self, response):
    "this method "
    jsonResponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    flexibleItem = {}
    flexibleItem['source'] = self.Source
    flexibleItem['action'] = self.Action
    flexibleItem['category'] = self.Category
    jsonResponse = self.attributesXMLParser.correctResponse(jsonResponse)

    flexibleItem[self.linkAttributeName] = self.attributesXMLParser.getPageLink(flexibleItem[self.linkAttributeName], flexibleItem)
    meta = dict()
    meta['flexibleItem'] = flexibleItem
    if self.ParseDetailsPage=="TRUE" : "this value is from XML file"
         print "TRUE"
         yield Request(flexibleItem[self.linkAttributeName],callback=self.parseDetails,dont_filter=True)
         print "oooooo"
    else :
         yield flexibleItem

def parseDetails(self, response):
    print "in parse details "
    jsonResponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    print jsonResponse
    flexibleItem = {}
    for key in self.Attributes:
       flexibleItem[key]= .....bla bla bla
    yield flexibleItem
```

Comment: Please share whole code so we can test it out.

Comment: add some code from the parse function that is yielding request.

Comment: I edited the post and waiting for an answer , Thank you .